# Substitution for object name

Tags: vba, object

I am trying to make a object change color based on a result of a ping. I have a object for each device I am pinging, the objects name are the same as the computer. So I am trying to substitute the object name with a varible that I can pass throw with a For statement.

```
Private Sub PING_Click()
Dim strCommand As String
Dim strPing As String
Dim myIP() As String
ReDim myIP(0 To 3) As String

myIP(0) = "computer1"
myIP(1) = "computer2"
myIP(2) = "computer3"
myIP(3) = "computer4"



For i = 0 To 3
MsgBox myIP(i)


strCommand = "%ComSpec% /C %SystemRoot%\system32\ping.exe -n 1 -w 500    " & myIP(i) & " | " & "%SystemRoot%\system32\find.exe /i " & Chr(34) & "TTL=" & Chr(34)
strPing = fShellRun(strCommand)

objcol = myIP(i) & ".ForegroundColor"

If strPing = "" Then
    objcol = 255
Else
    objcol = 65280

End If

Next i

End

End Sub
```

My problem is at

```
    objcol = myIP(i) & ".ForegroundColor"

If strPing = "" Then
    objcol = 255
Else
    objcol = 65280
```

For some reason it does not change the object's color. It does it just fine, if I hard code, the variable for example

```
    objcol = myIP(i) & ".ForegroundColor"

If strPing = "" Then
    computer1.ForegroundColor = 255
Else
    computer1.ForegroundColor = 65280
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: that's because `objcol` is a `Variant` which at first is equal to a `String` of "computer1.ForegroundColor", "computer2.ForegroundColor", etc... which then all you do is change it equal to `255` or `65280`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the line:

```
computer1.foregroundcolor
```

where "Computer1" represents an object whose foregroundcolor you can change with:

```
objcol
```

which is a string which has the value of "computer1.foregroundcolor".

In order to do this you would need to create an array of your objects like so:

```
Dim myIP() As Object
ReDim myIP(0 To 3) As Object

myIP(0) = computer1
myIP(1) = computer2
myIP(2) = computer3
myIP(3) = computer4

For i = 0 To 3
MsgBox myIP(i)


strCommand = "%ComSpec% /C %SystemRoot%\system32\ping.exe -n 1 -w 500    " &    myIP(i).name & " | " & "%SystemRoot%\system32\find.exe /i " & Chr(34) & "TTL=" & Chr(34)
strPing = fShellRun(strCommand)



    If strPing = "" Then
        myIP(i).foregroundcolor = 255
    Else
        myIP(i).foregroundcolor = 65280

    End If

Next i

End

End Sub
```

This assumes that you have computer1, computer2 available as objects to put into your array and that these objects have a ".name" property that contains the names "computer1", "computer2" etc.

Comment: Yep that work perfectly, Thanks 

It did have to add Set in front of myIP(0)
set myIP(0) = computer1
set myIP(1) = computer2
set myIP(2) = computer3
set myIP(3) = computer4

Answer (score 2):

A `String` isn't an *object reference*; you simply can't do that.

As [already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28728399/substitution-for-object-name#comment45743362_28728399), all you're doing is re-assigning the strings' values:

```
objcol = myIP(i) & ".ForegroundColor" ' objcol is "[computername].ForegroundColor"

...

objcol = 255 ' objcol is now "255"
```

---

You could have a `Scripting.Dictionary` with `[computername]` as keys and the actual object references as values, and then do something like this:

```
Dim mappings As New Scripting.Dictionary
mappings.Add "computer1", computer1
mappings.Add "computer2", computer2
...

mappings(myIP(i)).ForegroundColor = IIf(strPing = vbNullString, 255, 65280)
```